# How can I make a Table mobile responsive

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table mobile responsive. The first thing I would love to do is to decrease the width size of the table headings and then enable the table data to have one complete row for each data.

I am trying to get my table to look like the attached picture on mobile.[image]

```css
.email-table table{
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
td, th {
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
td{
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

td:last-of-type{
  font-weight: 700;
}
.attachment{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20%;
  align-items: center;
  
  
}
.first-clip span:last-of-type{
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.last-clip{
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.attachment span:last-of-type{
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.attachment span:first-of-type img{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.text-attachment{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.text-attachment span:first-of-type{
  transform: translateX(-18px);
}
.second-text{
  transform: translateX(5px);
}

.text-attachment span:last-of-type{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #5E5D5D;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
.second-text span:last-of-type{
  transform: translateX(-10px);
}
td  img{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: translateX(-30px);
}

th{
  background-color: #EEEDED;
  border-top: 3px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #dddddd;
}
th:not(:last-child){
  color: #5E5D5D;
}
.date>span img{
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
tr:not(:first-of-type):hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  background-color: #EEEDED;
}
```

```html
<div class="email-table">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>To</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th class="date">Date <span><img src="./assets/icon_arrow01.svg" alt=""></span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa@example.com</td>
            <td>zzz.zzz@example.com</td>
            <td>[ HR-888 ] Notice of official announcement</td>
            <td>0:20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bbb.bbbb@exam... </td>
            <td>yyy@example.com</td>
            <td>[web:333] "Web Contact"</td>
            <td>0:10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ccc@example.com </td>
            <td>
                <div class="text-attachment">
                    <span>xxx@example.com, ...</span>
                    <span>+1</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Happy New Year! Greetings for the New Year.</td>
            <td>
                <div class="attachment first-clip">
                    <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span>
                    <span>0:00</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ddd.dddd@exam...</td>
            <td>
                <div class="text-attachment second-text">
                    <span>vvv.vvv@example.com, ... </span>
                    <span>+1</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>[HR-887(Revised: Office Expansion Project Team)] Notice of off... </td>
            <td>Jan 01 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>eee@example.com</td>
            <td>
                <div class="text-attachment">
                    <span>sss@example.com, .... </span>
                    <span>+2</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>[Github] Logout page</td>
            <td>Jan 01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>fff.ffff@example.c... </td>
            <td>qqq.qqq@example.com</td>
            <td>［dev］ Postfix 3.1.12 / 3.2.9 / 3.3.4 / 3.4.5</td>
            <td>Jan 01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ggg@example.com </td>
            <td>ppp@example.com</td>
            <td>Re: [Github] Brush-up on loading animation </td>
            <td>Jan 01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>hhh.hhh@examp...</td>
            <td>ooo.ooo@example.com</td>
            <td>Workplace Summary for sample, Inc.: Jun 2 - Jun 9</td>
            <td>
                <div class="attachment">
                    <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span>
                    <span>Jan 01</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>iii@example.com</td>
            <td>nnn@example.com</td>
            <td>I love you</td>
            <td>
                <div class="attachment last-clip">
                    <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span>
                    <span>2019/12/31</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pablo-Diego-...</td>
            <td>Pablo-Diego-José-Francisc...
            </td>
            <td>[info:888] ABC EQUIPMENT COMPANY</td>
            <td>2019/12/31</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I, first of all, tried to make the header much smaller but that does not even work. I am totally lost at the steps I need to take to make this look good on mobile.

Comment: I think you should recognize the device and recreate the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick for this sort of layout is to throw away the default table styling entirely.

Use `display: contents` to stop the `tbody` element from generating a box. Then use `display: flex` on the table to make it lay out the `tr` elements in a non-tabular column.

Then each `tr` can be styled as a CSS Grid, and the various elements positioned on that.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    background: #AAA
  }
  table {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 10%;
    background: white;
  }
  tbody,
  tfoot {
    display: contents;
  }
  thead {
    display: none;
  }
  tr {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 1px 1px;
    grid-template-areas: "From Date" "To Date" "Subject Date";
    border-bottom: solid #aaa 1px;
  }
  td {
    padding: 3px;
  }
  td:nth-child(1) {
    grid-area: From;
  }
  td:nth-child(2) {
    grid-area: To;
  }
  td:nth-child(3) {
    grid-area: Subject;
  }
  td:nth-child(4) {
    grid-area: Date;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="email-table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th class="date">Date <span><img src="./assets/icon_arrow01.svg" alt=""></span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>aaa@example.com</td>
      <td>zzz.zzz@example.com</td>
      <td>[ HR-888 ] Notice of official announcement</td>
      <td>0:20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bbb.bbbb@exam... </td>
      <td>yyy@example.com</td>
      <td>[web:333] "Web Contact"</td>
      <td>0:10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ccc@example.com </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-attachment">
          <span>xxx@example.com, ...</span>
          <span>+1</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Happy New Year! Greetings for the New Year.</td>
      <td>
        <div class="attachment first-clip">
          <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span>
          <span>0:00</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ddd.dddd@exam...</td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-attachment second-text">
          <span>vvv.vvv@example.com, ... </span>
          <span>+1</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>[HR-887(Revised: Office Expansion Project Team)] Notice of off... </td>
      <td>Jan 01 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>eee@example.com</td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-attachment">
          <span>sss@example.com, .... </span>
          <span>+2</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>[Github] Logout page</td>
      <td>Jan 01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>fff.ffff@example.c... </td>
      <td>qqq.qqq@example.com</td>
      <td>［dev］ Postfix 3.1.12 / 3.2.9 / 3.3.4 / 3.4.5</td>
      <td>Jan 01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ggg@example.com </td>
      <td>ppp@example.com</td>
      <td>Re: [Github] Brush-up on loading animation </td>
      <td>Jan 01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hhh.hhh@examp...</td>
      <td>ooo.ooo@example.com</td>
      <td>Workplace Summary for sample, Inc.: Jun 2 - Jun 9</td>
      <td>
        <div class="attachment">
          <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span>
          <span>Jan 01</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>iii@example.com</td>
      <td>nnn@example.com</td>
      <td>I love you</td>
      <td>
        <div class="attachment last-clip">
          <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span>
          <span>2019/12/31</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pablo-Diego-...</td>
      <td>Pablo-Diego-José-Francisc...
      </td>
      <td>[info:888] ABC EQUIPMENT COMPANY</td>
      <td>2019/12/31</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```